# How to forward arguments from one function to another in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell function which wraps another function. I want my function to take a variable number of arguments and to pass those onto the wrapped function. Is there anyway to do this?

Specifically what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
function MakeRequest() {
    if ($session) {
        $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $session $args
    } else {
        $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable session $args
    }
    $resp
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use splatting for this:

```powershell
function MakeRequest() {
    if ($session) {
        $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $session @args
    } else {
        $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable session @args
    }
    $resp
}
```

Type this for more help:

```powershell
help about_Splatting
```